# UK Private Sector Receipts from the EU

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union, budget

The UK's membership fee in 2018 according to [full fact](https://fullfact.org/europe/our-eu-membership-fee-55-million/) goes from a £17bn gross payment, less rebate and public sector spending to a £9bn net payment.
[image: Net Public Sector Payment]

Specifically, this image shows this does not include Private Sector payments. A link in the article to a [UK government report](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/814387/190618_HMT_2018_Annual_Statement_on_European_Finances_print.pdf#page=14) shows a further £2.3bn is paid directly to private concerns.

> The EU makes some payments directly to the private sector, for example to
>   carry out research activities. These payments do not appear in public sector
>   accounts. It is estimated that in 2016 these receipts were worth £2.3 billion
>   (see Technical Annex B). These payments are not included in Table 3.A or
>   Tables 3.C-F, which provide data only on receipts channelled through the
>   public sector.

However, I've been unable to find any breakdown of these monies.
Who in the Private Sector receives the £2.3bn from EU?

Comment: There's nothing breaking down the payments in Technical Annex B in case you're wondering.

Comment: I assume that a significant part of the spending towards private sector is through the EU research program H2020. There are lots of documents and figures but I don't know how to find the exact figure for the UK private sector. https://ec.europa.eu/info/funding-tenders/opportunities/portal/screen/opportunities/horizon-dashboard

Comment: Agriculture is probably the largest private beneficiary, see http://www.europarl.europa.eu/external/html/budgetataglance/default_en.html#united_kingdom

Comment: @Erwan Are the CAP payments not included in the Public Sector Payment? "Common Agricultural Policy (CAP) Pillar 1, funded through the
European Agricultural Guarantee Fund (EAGF)" Then table C3, lists EAGF as Public Sector Reciepts (£3bn in 2018). Should I add this to the Question?

Comment: you're right. I don't know if the agriculture budget is limited to CAP though?

Comment: @Erwan me either. It's why I'm asking :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the details either, but it's basically EU subsidies. As point out by Erwan in the comments, they [chiefly revolve](http://www.europarl.europa.eu/external/html/budgetataglance/default_en.html#united_kingdom) around farmers and fishermen. There's also a laundry list of grants for research and startups. And while not technically private entities directly, there are also grants for public interest projects -- think roads, metro or tram systems, cultural centers, museums, etc. (Which, in some countries, get abused to funnel EU funds to private interests, but that's a separate problem.)

Comment: According to [UK Gov](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/814387/190618_HMT_2018_Annual_Statement_on_European_Finances_print.pdf#page=14) The Cap payments via EAGF are listed as public receipts. The fishing money comes under EMFF and isn't listed in the tables, but from the text appears to be grouped with EAGF and other public payments. So these monies would be part of the £4.3bn Public receipts not the £2.3bn private receipts. Unless the agricultural and fishing payments are split between both groups?